# How to change mysql delimiter through php

Tags: php, mysql, events, procedure

I created an event with a set of sql statements in mysql terminal, It is working fine. But I want to create this event from php script. My query is below.

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE EVENT e_cart

ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 3 MINUTE

DO

BEGIN

SET @var_orderid = '';

SET @var_orderid = (SELECT orderid FROM order WHERE id=308);

IF @var_orderid = NULL THEN

UPDATE order SET status=1 WHERE id=308;

END IF;
END |

DELIMITER ;
```

This results in :-

> Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER |
>                   CREATE EVENT e_cart
>               ON SCHEDULE AT CUR' at line 1

How do I execute this event from php script?

Comment: At first run `delimiter |` from php script, after that another part.

Comment: If we execute event part after execute the delimiter |, How mysql recognize the  multiple statements in event. IT recognize up to CREATE EVENT e_cart ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 3 MINUTE DO BEGIN SET @var_orderid = ''; rest of the part will omit and give error

Answer (score 7):

DELIMITER isn't MySQL server command but MySQL CLI/Query Browser/Workbench etc. It only says when to send command to MySQL server.

Omit DELIMITER and send whole CREATE EVENT statement as one command, it should work.

Comment: If we omit delimiter, it gives error. CREATE EVENT e_cart ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 3 MINUTE DO BEGIN SET @var_orderid = ''; Mysql thinks statement has completed with in the middle of event when the semi colon comes in the statement. So event has broken and gives error.
Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET cart_orderid = (SELECT orderid FROM bvira_bargain_subsession WHERE session_'

Comment: It works. Thanks lucek. I removed Delimiter and made as one command.

Comment: @Jeyakumar can you please share how you solved the semicolon issue without using a delimiter substitute?

Comment: For me it wasn't a delimiter issue, but that I was missing the BEGIN and END keywords, which made the event only schedule the first statement.